# ArrayBlockingQueue with priority waiting list

Tags: java, concurrency

I currently have a Spring dispatcher ensuring various concurrency limitation policies based on bounded queues.

Basically, multiple request types are handled, some memory expensive, other less, and the request threads happening to hit the memory expensive tasks put a token in a bounded blocking queue (ArrayBlockingQueue), so that only N of them end up actually running, while the other end up waiting.

Now, the waiting list is internally managed by a ReentrantLock, which in turns leverages a Condition implementation fund in AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer that uses a linked list, which notifies the longest waiting thread when a token is removed from the queue.

Now I need a different behavior, so that the list maintained by the Condition is sorted by a user defined priority too (straight one, no counter-starvation measures needed for lower priority requests).

Unfortunately the classes in question have a wall of "final" declarations making it hard to inject this seemingly small behavioral change.

Is there any concurrent data structure out there providing the behavior I'm looking for, or that would allow customization? 
Alternatively, suggestions to implement it without rewriting ArrayBlockinQueue/ReentrantLock/Condition from scratch?

Note: really looking for a bounded blocking queue with priority in the waiting list, other approaches requiring a redesign of the whole application, secondary execution thread pools and the like are unfortunately not feasible (time and material limitations)

Comment: To be clear, you want the queue sorted by *both* waiting time *and* priority? Lexicographically, with priority more important than waiting time?

Comment: Ideally, on both, that but that would make the priority time varying. One with fixed priority values would do, at least for starters :-D